# How to pass second value in JSF validator?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a simple JSF input form into edit page and Validator which checks the value for duplication:

```
<td>Name</td>
<td>
    <h:outputText value="#{ud.name}"
                  rendered="#{not DCProfileTabGeneralController.editable}" />
    <h:inputText id="dcname" value="#{ud.name}" rendered="#{DCProfileTabGeneralController.editable}"
                 validator="#{ValidatorDatacenterController.validateDatacenterName}" autocomplete="off">
        <f:ajax event="blur" render="dcnamevalidator" />
    </h:inputText>
    <h:message id="dcnamevalidator" for="dcname" />
</td>

public void validateDatacenterName(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value){
....
}
```

I'm interested is there any possible way to send a second value which will be used into the validation process?

Comment: From your actual code sample, it looks like there's no reason to send another value. It would be better to explain your functional requirement to get better guidance or your motives to send a second argument to the validator.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`<f:attribute>` comes to mind. Add one to the inputtext and retrieve it in the validator.

```
<h:inputText id="dcname".....
<f:attribute name="param" value="myparam" /> 
</h:inputText>
```

And:

```
String param = (String) component.getAttributes().get("param");
```

Can get the value from EL. Good luck

Answer (score 2):

You can add a postValidate event to validate multiple fields , like

```
<f:event listener="#{bean.validationMethod}" type="postValidate" />
```

this should fire before model updates and you can get the new value for different component with

```
FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(); 
UIComponent components = event.getComponent();
UIInput param1 = (UIInput) components.findComponent("param1");
UIInput param2 = (UIInput) components.findComponent("param2");
```

If the validation fails , call the FacesContext renderResponse method to skip model update.

Comment: I have used this some. I like to use f:ajax with this so I don't need to find the component and that stuff. This ofc requires a longer scope then requestscoped